# Importing excel files into a openpxl workbook - Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to load a dumby set of excel files to do some copy/paste procedures. When I load it and print it it just says: <openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook object at 0x000001E239441FD0>. Here is what I am trying:

import openpyxl as opxl

wb = opxl.load_workbook(r'mypath')

Comment: [read an existing workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) + [write to a workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior of `load_workbook` - it returns a `Workbook` object.

You then need to reference the individual worksheet (the name on the worksheet tab in the Excel file):

```
wb = opxl.load_workbook(r'mypath')
ws = wb['worksheet1']                  (or whatever the worksheet/tab is named)
```

Then you can read the data, e.g.:

```
for row in ws:
    print(row[0].value)
```

prints all the values in column A.